# Best way to group datetime into days but done based on id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is similar to the one below:

```
time                                value1    value2    id
2020-07-20 00:00:00.621000+00:00    104       5         car1
2020-07-20 00:00:04.622000+00:00    105       10        car1
2020-07-21 00:00:09.341000+00:00    98        3         car2
2020-07-21 00:00:03.322000+00:00    23        9         car2
2020-07-22 00:00:00.201000+00:00    90        4         car3
2020-07-22 00:00:07.922000+00:00    49        7         car3
```

Is there a way to group these time datetime values into days, but that would be respective to the id? I am trying to find the average of these values.

So something like this:

```
time        value1    value2    id
2020-07-20  104.5     5         car1
2020-07-21  60.5      6         car2
2020-07-22  69.5      6.5      car3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.groupby([df['time'].dt.normalize(), 'id']).mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
                       time    id  value1  value2
0 2020-07-20 00:00:00+00:00  car1   104.5     7.5
1 2020-07-21 00:00:00+00:00  car2    60.5     6.0
2 2020-07-22 00:00:00+00:00  car3    69.5     5.5
```

Comment: Would there be a way to keep other columns when this is done?

Comment: What other columns? Your sample data has only 4. Also, this would retain all *numerical* columns.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of something else in my dataframe! Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

coerce time to datetime in format of YYYY-MM-DD and use it in the groupby

```
df.groupby([(pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%M-%d')),'id']).mean().reset_index()


        time    id  value1  value2
0  2020-00-20  car1   104.5     7.5
1  2020-00-21  car2    60.5     6.0
2  2020-00-22  car3    69.5     5.5
```